# HTML <input> size attribute not working?

Tags: html, input

I have the following element which specifies the size="15". However the rendered element, which has the size attribute, has a width that fits 25 characters and could fit 30 or so if maxlength was greater? Maxlength does limit the # of characters.

```
<input id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" type="text" maxlength="25" size="15" />
```

Comment: are you applying come CSS to that element ?

Comment: The size isn't the actual size. If you have a play here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_size You can see how a size of 1 is actually many pixels in width.

Comment: error: "some" instead of "come"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably depends on the font you are using, and what character you are testing with!

Answer (score 10):

#### Monospaced Font

The best results I've seen came through using a monospace font:

```
<input type="text" size="4" style="font-family:monospace" />
```

Online Example: http://jsbin.com/epagi/edit Rendered neatly in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE.

If you're using a variable-width font, you would have to use scripting to get a better guess as to what the expected width would be, but as you said, this isn't very elegant.

#### Variable-Width Font

I tried to work up a reasonable-simple solution for variable-width fonts, but ultimately  you will need to see if it fits your project or not.

Basically what I did was set the `text-transform` of particular inputs to `uppercase` to get a semi-consistent expectation for how wide something *will be* when filled out with text. I then applied a classname that indicated the field should be auto-sized, and how many chars we're expecting: `sizeMe-4`. Using jQuery, I collected all of these inputs, and split this classname to get the number of chars expected.

I extended the String object to include a repeat method which allows me to easily create a string of the expected size, and add it to an ad-hoc span element to get the width. This width was then retroactively applied to the initial input element. The span is then discarded.

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/epagi/2/edit

For convenience, here's the code:

```
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" class="sizeMe-4" 
       style="text-transform:uppercase" />
```

--

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(num) {
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}

$(function(){
  $(":input[class^='sizeMe']").each(function(){
    var size = Number($(this).attr("class").split("-").pop());
    var newW = $("<span>").text( "X".repeat(size) ).appendTo("body");
    $(this).width( $(newW).width() );
    $(newW).remove();
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of outdated bad information
Good luck getting

```
 size="100" to work in Chrome, not going to work
```

for inline style

```
style="width:20px"
```

Comment: Well, I had been using a homegrown css framework and not my favorite bootstrap so `size` was not working.  perhaps someone else is in that same boat

Answer (score 1):

My case is:

when using an outer div with a class "input-group", the size or inline style will not work at all. Removing this class of "input-group" if possible will make it work.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required style="width:20px">
</div>
```