# What is the point of "size" for HTML input text?

Tags: html

For the `size` element of an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), which [`type` is "text"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text), we expect it (as the [MDN's documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)) to correspond to the number of characters:

> unsigned long: Returns / Sets the element's size attribute, containing
> visual size of the control. This value is in pixels unless the value
> of ***type is text or password, in which case, it is an integer number
> of characters***. Applies only when type is set to text, search, tel,
> url, email, or password; otherwise it is ignored.

Here below is [W3C's definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-size):

> The size attribute gives the ***number of characters that***, in a
> visual rendering, ***the user agent is to allow the user to see***
> while editing the element's value.

However, in this sample we see that that rule is not respected at all:

```html
1 <input type="text" size="1" value="123456789"><br/>
2 <input type="text" size="2" value="123456789"><br/>
3 <input type="text" size="3" value="123456789"><br/>
4 <input type="text" size="4" value="123456789"><br/>
```

Is the documentation wrong and if it is, what is the purpose of that `size` attribute of the `input` HTML element?

Comment: It seems to me like the MDN documentation is technically correct, but misleading. MDN missed out the crucial part of the spec containing "that **at least** that many characters are visible" (Implying it's a minimum visual size, based on characters rather than an absolute amount of characters contained)

Comment: @DBS *at least*, does not mean that the width of control is *proportional*

Comment: The MDN documentation is a bit of a mess. It seems to be an amalgam of information culled badly from the HTML 4 spec and the HTML 5/Living spec. It's completely wrong on the bit about pixels (as was the HTML 4 spec), and as DBS says, it's the _minimum_ number of characters visible inside the input.

Comment: Keep in mind MDN is wiki-editable by the public; don't rely on it for authoritative information. Rely on the spec only (and comparisons against actual browser implementations, which do often differ)

Comment: @TylerH, MDN is not like wiki, you should be GitHub member, and also you should should fork the repository and then merge request should be approved by an admin, to be published

Comment: @TylerH and why did you remove W3C tag? is a W3C definition we are talking about

Comment: @serge The W3C is an organization, and asking about an organization is not something that's on-topic here; only programming questions. Your question is about the HTML specification, which is covered by the [tag:html] tag. The W3C tag is a bad meta tag that should not be used.

Comment: @TylerH, please don't vandalize my tags, W3C is not only an organization, but also the standards it publishes, so, I am asking about a **W3C definition** versus **MDN definition**. If moderators consider W3C should not be asked here, they should remove the W3C tag instead; please also remove these ones then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c

Comment: W3C is not a definition, it is an organization. You are referring to the *HTML5 specification*, in this case the latest working draft from May 2011. No one refers to the specification as a "W3C" just like no one refers to the HTML living standard as a "WHATWG". The tag itself refers to the organization, which makes it a meta tag that is off-topic. I am cleaning up questions that are only referring to HTML matters (like this question), CSS matters, XHTML matters, etc., but it is slow-going. Made even more slowly by misguided users who think a bad tag is somehow good (or worse, required).

Comment: @TylerH if you prefer the "W3C`'s` definition"

Comment: The [tag:w3c] tag does not belong on this question. Please leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the value of `size` as an integer seems to work fine:

```html
20 <input type="text" size=20 value="123456789"><br/>
02 <input type="text" size=2  value="123456789"><br/>
05 <input type="text" size=5  value="123456789"><br/>
```

---

Visual output on Chrome 101.0.4951.64 on [macOS v12.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey):

[image]

---

The `2` and `5` more look like `2.5`. Please see the quote from MDN describing why.

Quote from MDN:

> **Since character widths vary**, this may or may not be exact and should not be relied upon to be so; **the resulting input may be narrower or wider than the specified number of characters**, depending on the characters and the font (font settings in use).

Comment: what do you mean "fine"? is the same behavior like in the OP

Comment: Did you run the snippet? There totally different sizes here, and showing the amount of chars as `size` attribute says.

Comment: and, after all, there is no difference if you put `size="20"` versus `size=20`

Comment: Apparently there is. You're not seeing the same as my screenshot?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/pcHcWfBnKZeG.png

Comment: Mmm thats kinda strange. Seems inconsistent.

Comment: what is your chrome version you use?

Comment: did you try in the **private navigation** with all plugins inactive?

Comment: Yes, private/incognito without any plugins/addons. Firefox browser is showing the same result as your screenshot. Safari shows the desired result as seen in my screenshot.

Comment: what is your Chrome version?

Comment: My Chrome/OS versions are mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ah, that is macOS... that is, I have, like the majority of users, Windows....

Comment: and so you did observe the difference between `size="20"` and `size=20` on MacOS?

Comment: Yea, your snippet [looks like this](https://i.ibb.co/RYtW9ps/image.png) where my snippets renders [like this](https://i.ibb.co/x8MV6xw/image.png).

Comment: as per this one https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2 W3 recommends "using quotation marks even when it is possible to eliminate them", so I don't think this should be a problem using "20"

Comment: could you combine `="3"` and `=3` in your snippet and render the output? for me is and should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down a little bit.
What does size really do?

> The size attribute specifies the visible width,... 
> Tip: To specify the maximum number of characters  allowed in the  element, use the maxlength attribute.
>
> Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

So lets go for the specification:

> - size = cdata [CN] 
>   This attribute tells the user agent the initial width of the control. The width is given in pixels except when type attribute has the value "text" or "password". In that case, its value refers to the (integer) number of characters.
>
> Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT

Since, why, whatever not all browsers seems to work the same way in terms of sizes etc, there will be some difference from client to client.

If you want to limit the input you have to go for:

```
maxlenght="8"
```

But there are way more options to handle your inputs in html, link patterns & types:

```
 <input type="text" id="pattern_of_3" name="pattern_of_3" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

Like this the input must be as the pattern expect its, we could add maxlength
but it's not really needed at this point.

And we can go on with types:

```
type="email" pattern=".+@domain\.com"
type="url" name="url" id="url" pattern="https://.*"
```

Since we can use patterns and maxlength to make it work, we can use CSS to adjust what the inputs will look like.

How to style an input with CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
width : 20px;
more: css;
}
```

It is possible to do this with any type of input.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

Let's go a bit derper into the definition:

[Definition of size](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-size)

> If the attribute is present, then its value must be parsed using the rules for parsing non-negative integers, and if the result is a number greater than zero, then the user agent should ensure that at least that many characters are visible.

Then we can find the first thing that can be a source of the different outputs:

> ensure that at least

It states that the user agent/client (browser) has to show at least that many characters, not that it has to show that number of characters.

Let's go a bit more through everything as you can read here:

[Size attribute for an input field not being honored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699575/size-attribute-for-an-input-field-not-being-honored)

That problem exists for years.
So if `size = x`  is not defined in px it will vary, even fonts can than influence the result.

Now lets go back to the client/user agent/browser:

If they still handle the `size="2"` in em instead of px,

> most web browsers have settled on using the number of em
> every font used will influence the out put.

So smaller font means = you see more characters;

Bigger font means = you see less characters;

At this point neither the definition or the usage is wrong,
it´s just missing the point that the visual output can be
influenced by other factors like `font` and `font-size`.

The same "erroneous" information is specified in the HTML4 Spec, the HTML5 spec, Sitepoint, Mozilla Developer Network, and Microsoft's MSDN library. So it isn't just W3Schools' fault.

Comment: the maxlength has no impact on visual appearance of the input

Comment: I put a small edit to post, if you want to style inputs use css.

Comment: the OP is about to clarify the meaning of the size attribute, the validation is not the subject here

Comment: also, the width **in pixels** is clear, is not a problem, the question is rather about the width **in symbols**

Comment: The width in symbols is not defined with "size", its defined in addition of "maxlength".

Comment: please see the size definition in the OP

Answer (score -1):

'Size' is used for the size of the *input* element itself, not for the maximum allowed length of input. If you want to limit your input for size, you can use:

`<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="123456789">`

Comment: visually that has no effect, I mean "1" is not just 1 element visible

Comment: that is size of input element, so as you can see here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_size ... if you have some styles appliled to input element, which affect width, then it doesnt change anything from visual poitn of view

Comment: we don't speak about other styles might be applied. We take just the input in the codepen without any styling

Comment: This does not address OP's question, which is about the number if characters displayed in the input element, not the number of characters allowed in the input element.